# Why am I getting an 'explosive' GARCH on this series?

Tags: time-series, garch

I am fairly new to time series econometrics and I am working with a series

I want to model the in-sample second moments. I am not super sure that this is stationary, but I rely on the ADF saying that it is. This would imply that the variance shocks are explosive, and I don't see that in the data at all.

How can I make sense of this?

Comment: Could you actually include the two graphs and the $\alpha+\beta$ value you are referring to?

Comment: Does this data involve capital?   The future value of the use of capital should be increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because you haven't correctly dealt with pulses,level/step shifts,seasonal pulses and/or local time trends which reflect modifications to the expected value (first moment) remedies ... you are all about trying to remedy the second moment .. There may be deterministic change points in variance rather than stochastic which is what you are assuming OR change points in parameters both of which are much less complicated that the complications you are asserting.

Occam's razor comes to mind in terms of keeping the model simple BUT NOT TOO SIMPLE and introducing complications SLOWLY until one has generated a white noise error process with minimal structure. !

As usual if you post your data in a csv file I will try and help u further.

I might surmise that that you are mis-specifying the model and it is not really a model requiring the complications you are asserting.Only your data knows for sure !